# Error: 'Dcdensity' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rdd'

Tags: r

Even though I used the 'Dcdensity' function from the rdd package successfully two month ago.
R studio only returns the following error to me when I try to use it:
'Dcdensity' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rdd'
Yet, it still works in the old rmd file from my last project from where I copy and pasted the code into my new rmd file where it only creates the error...

I already reinstalled r and r studio and also the rdd package multiple times

Comment: Check spelling. Maybe no capital D. Or two caps. DCdensity?

Comment: It was a typo so should be closed

Answer (score 0):

if you remember the version number which worked for you, you can install that specific version of that package like this:

```
install.packages("rdd", version = "version_number")
```

if you do not know the version of rdd that worked for your previous project, you can check with this:

```
packageVersion("rdd")
```

Comment: thanks for the tip! But I checked and I am still using the same version that is just not working for me anymore

Answer (score 0):

There’s a `DCdensity` in pkg:rdd. So try

```
library(rdd) # and rerun code with proper spelling.
```